# Como fazer com que o meu Form Principal saiba quando um form secundário foi fechado, sem usar Parent e Child?

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho o meu form principal (imagem abaixo), e nele um *Split Container*. 
Abro um form secundário (o que esta sendo exibido no momento) no `panel2` do `SplitContainer`, no qual o usuário seleciona uma conta para efetuar movimentações financeiras.

Assim que ele escolher a conta, e clicar no botão `continuar` desse form, se estiver tudo OK, o *form* de seleção deve ser fechado e, no seu lugar, mostrar outro *form* com as opções disponíveis.

Como posso informar o meu *form* principal que o *form* de seleção foi fechado, para ele poder carregar o próximo *form*?

Penso em utilizar eventos e *delegate*, é o correto?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, seria correto usar eventos ou *delegates* nesse caso. No caso de *WinForms*, não vejo problema ao colocar um *handler* de evento no *parent* pro `OnClosed` do filho:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newForm = new Form1();
    newForm.Closed += newForm_Closed; ;
    newForm.ShowDialog();
}

void newForm_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Text = "Fechado";
}
```

Poderia também passar um `delegate` no construtor do form filho e guardar a instância. Assim, ao fechar, bastava chamar o `delegate`.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu queria. Tinha esquecido como fazia isso, apesar de ser bem simples. Valeu!